# What does "Ambiguous output redirect" mean?

Tags: php, unix, shell

I have a PHP script that I want to call on some form action.

This command works fine:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But it all go wrong when I add arguments in the command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php --var=value > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

it returns "Ambiguous output redirect".

I have read this http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/ article too, and have tried almost everything possible as far as I can understand, and still have no idea how to fix it.

Please help me.

Comment: does it work without --var?, just "/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php value > /dev/null 2>&1 &", and get it from array $argv

Comment: I am using standard FreeBSD shell

Comment: @sukinsa yes it works fine without var

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using csh or one of its variants, use:

```
... >&/dev/null
```

Comment: no i am using simple PHP shell_exec command with 

/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php --var=value > /dev/null 2>&1 &

and it returns Ambiguous output redirect

Comment: but the shell_exec winds up calling a 'real' shell ;-). Make a php command like shell_exec('Echo $SHELL') and let us know the output. OR if you know that it is calling bash, then tell us that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php --var=value > &1 &
```

And let us know the consequences of running this command.

Do you get output properly redirected?

I believe that this error is somehow related to user rights on the OS. I ran your exact same command on a test environment running AiX using root user and it worked OK but once I tried as some other user , I get the 'Ambiguous Redirect error'.

Either the user does not have access to the STDERR,STDOUT pointer or access permissions restrict redirect chaining in some way.

Hope this helps.
EDIT:
Maybe this link can help:
http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-9.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q script.php --var=value > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: already tried this, didn't worked .. please help me if anyone can give me some inside (a bit more detail) how this works .. and how we can make practical use of it.